# copy/paste of large amount of text to terminal leads to scrambled/missing characters

Tags: terminal, bash, copy-paste, textmate

I work with TextMate and R over the terminal.
When pasting a lot of code (CMD+C/CMD+V, e.g. 60 lines) it sometimes happens that few characters in the code are scrambled, which then leads to error messages and wrong code execution.

For example:

> col <- ifelse(...

is turning into

> col < col < cse(...

or

> onlyDF

is turning into

> oalyDF

These character-replacements seem very random and it is difficult to predict when it happens.

The problem is also described here for iterm2:
https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/3160

The explanation provided there is that it is a bug in bash that can lead to buffered input to get lost due to paste speed.

Has anyone experienced these problems and found a work-around for the native terminal app in Mac OS? (e.g. by modifying the paste speed, if that is possible in terminal)

Comment: If you read to the very bottom of that 2 year old thread, there's an entry that states:  *To change the speed that "paste slowly" pastes....*

Comment: indeed – but I am working with terminal, not iTerm. Since the problem seems to affect both apps, I am wondering if there is also a solution for the native terminal.

Comment: What program is running in the foreground in the terminal when you are pasting into it?

Comment: you can use Iterm2, Paste slowly in `edit -> paste special -> paste slowly`, see `https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/3160#note_1168791`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `pbpaste` command to get the text in the pasteboard without going through the vagaries of the terminal driver, buffer overruns, etc. To put the cut text into a new file, use:

```
pbpaste >myfile.txt
```

To append, use `>>`, etc. Similarly, you can feed the pasteboard's contents to other commands as input:

```
pbpaste | somecommand
```

And if you use the `vi` editor, you can insert the pasteboard's contents into your file with:

```
:r !pbpaste
```

BTW, there's also a corresponding `pbcopy` command to put text into the pasteboard. Unlike standard file redirections, you *can* use this to nondestructively modify the contents of the pasteboard "in place":

```
pbpaste | sed 's/foo/bar/' | pbcopy
```

...and if you want to see the output as well:

```
pbpaste | sed 's/foo/bar/' | tee /dev/tty | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 5):

When I need to paste a lot of text into a Terminal application window, I use the `cat` command to transfer the text to a file. For example, I would enter the command below before pasting the text with the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> key combination.

```
cat >myfile.txt
```

When finished pasting text, enter the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> key combination. This will terminate the `cat` command.

> Note: The <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> key combination must be entered at the beginning of a line. If not at the beginning of a line after pasting the text, then press the <kbd>return</kbd> key before entering the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> key combination.

Comment: You can do it even more directly with `pbpaste >myfile.txt`. No need for Command-V, Control-D, etc.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson: You should post an new answer.